# How to Display Serial Number in ascending order in CGridview in Yii without taking a extra database field

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

How to Display Serial Number in ascending order like

```
1 Record Abc
2 Record Def
3 Record Xyz
```

in CGridview in Yii without taking a extra database field ?

Comment: Use sort in dataprovider?

Comment: As Peter said, use sort in dataprovider. And if you are having problem while doing that or some other issue, then we're gonna need to some some more code before we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps out:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'id'=>'accounts-grid',
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'header'=>'Serial Number',
            'value'=>'$row+1',
        ),
        'bank',
        'branch',
        'account',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{update} {delete}',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:40px;'),
            'updateButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("index", array("update"=>$data->uniq_id))',
            'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:40px;'),
        ),
    ),
    'summaryText'=>''
)); ?>
```

The `$row` variable is a zero-based row number

Answer (score 6):

It will work with pagination as well

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'status-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'columns'=>array(  
     array(
            'header'=>'SL No',
            'value'=>'$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1)',
           ),
     //Other fields
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer harikrishnan but my problem was solved using #ragingprodigy's above method....:) thanks.

Comment: This is the better answer because it is working with Pagination also.

Answer (score 0):

I found better answer with `sort` and `filter`.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'status-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'columns'=>array(  
     array(
            array(
               'name'=>'id',
               'value'=>'$this->grid->dataProvider->getSort()->getDirection($this->name) != "desc" ? $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1) : $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->itemCount - $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize - ($row)',
           ),
     //Other fields
    )
```